# Assessing the accuracy of OpenCV program

Tags: c++, opencv, false-positive

I have an OpenCV program that implements the ORB algorithm, I am using the value returned by the homography mask to determine if an object of interest is present.

`(mask.size() < 100)`

Obviously when I adjust this value the accuracy, in terms of false positives, changes, is there any way to determine the accuracy?

Comment: Take a set of samples. Evaluate them yourself and create a file with expected results. Run your algorithm against your samples and get the result of the algorithm writting them a another file. Make a program reading both files and printing a report about successes and failures.

Comment: My program is running on real time data (video stream). Would it be a fair comparison to test the accuracy on a set a still sample images?

Comment: You can do it on recorded videos